# single click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, latitude-longitude

i want to call this function on single click but it is not working on single click.

```
<input id="search" type="button" onClick="codeAddress();" value="Search Location" />

function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("box").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            a = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            b = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(a, b);
        } 
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    initialize();
}
```

Comment: " it is not working" this is the most detailed description of  a error i always get on this site

Comment: Are you including the Google Maps Javascript API v3? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is calling actually, but the actual problem in your code with is google code, please make sure first your code inside function is in a working condition.

```js
function codeAddress() {
  alert('hello its calling, the problem is in your google code, that is the actual problem!');
        }
```

```html
<input id="search" type="button" onClick="codeAddress();" value="Search Location" />
```

Comment: yes, codeAddress() is working, the error is in the function "initialize()" which i called in codeAddress(). I solved it...thank you Jagar7521

Comment: Yes that's what i have said you in my answer have you read that?